# how to convert array to dataframe in column only

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have tried to convert array to dataframe, and follow the documentation how to convert them.

here my script;

```
M = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=col)
c0 = M.quantile(0)
c1 = M.quantile(0.2)
c2 = M.quantile(0.4)
c3 = M.quantile(0.6)
c4 = M.quantile(0.8)
c5 = M.quantile(1)
d = np.array([c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5])              
output_table_1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

the ouput has 6 rows, is not my expected that i want convert it to 6 columns.
anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame([d])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `shape` of `d`:

```
In [186]: d.shape
Out[186]: (6, 1)
In [187]: pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[187]: 
     0
0  0.0
1  0.6
2  1.2
3  1.8
4  2.4
5  3.0
```

With a (1,6) shape:

```
In [188]: pd.DataFrame(d.T)
Out[188]: 
     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  0.0  0.6  1.2  1.8  2.4  3.0
```